# confusion for leverage browser caching age

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
wordpress ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 14 days"
</IfModule>
```

i use Above leverage cache code for my website and it improve my page speed but i am still confusing for leverage cache expire 14 day. it is good or affect my website please help me out...
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

It's supopse to do exactly what it says, once the resources are downloaded by a browser for the first time, the same browser should not try to download them again for 14 days.
Probably you don't want it on text/html, since that's what your wordpress pages with articles are. As for the rest of the MIME's, up to you how often you change them and how many returning visitors you have.